# How can I make an array variable in a class JS

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, p5.js

I am a python and java coder who is now learning java-script. For starting out I am trying to make snake, but I am getting a weird error in Snake.js.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>p5.js vers 0.5.2, Edit index.html to Change This Title</title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.2/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.2/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.2/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <script src="Apple.js"></script>
        <script src="Snake.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Apple.js**

```
// Currently empty

class Apple{
    constuctor(){
        
    }
}
```

**Index.js**

```
let snake;

function setup(){
    createCanvas(1000, 1000);
    background(0, 0, 0);

    snake = new Snake();
}

function draw(){
    background(0, 0, 0);
    snake.update();
    snake.show();
}

function keyPressed(){
    snake.move(key);
}
```

**Snake.js**

```
class Snake {
    constuctor(){
        this.position = p5.Vector(500, 500);
        this.direction = "Up";
        this.body = [[500, 500]];
        this.bodySize = 1;
    }

    update(){
        switch(this.direction){
            case "Up":
                this.position.add(0, -40);
                break;
            case "Down":
                this.position.add(0, 40);
                break;
            case "Left":
                this.position.add(-40, 0);
                break;
            case "Right":
                this.position.add(40, 0);
        }
        this.body.push([this.position.x, this.position.y]);
    }

    show(){
        // Havn't coded this yet.
    }

}
```

The error is : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined (Snake.js 23)

I have looked all over the internet and cannot find a solution

I don't understand why it is doing this because Snake.body isn't undefined I said this.body = [[500, 500]]

Please help me understand what to do!

Comment: Try bindong the `update` method in `Snake` constructor? `this.update = this.update.bind(this)`

Comment: first have you tried inserting `console.log(this.body)` before the `this.body.push...` line

Comment: When in console i type in snake.body : it logs undefined

Answer (score 1):

`constuctor` -> `constructor` (missing `r`)

and the error message `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` does not show up anymore

[EDIT]

and you forgot the `new` too ( `this.position = p5.Vector(500, 500);` -> `this.position = new p5.Vector(500, 500);` )

you can test it here :

https://jsfiddle.net/gqs64ban/